# How can I do performance testing on application for 20,000 user-request per second?

Tags: performance, jmeter

I want to put the load of 20000 user requests on my server to test can it handle this number of requests in a second.

I have put the Number of threads(user) - 20000
Ramp-up period (seconds) - 1
Loop count - 1

Output - It is showing 20 seconds **Avg** time after completing the script.

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting the output:
It is stating that the average server response time is 20 sec.

To check whether your server can handle 20000 users per sec,
run the test plan from non-GUI mode ([Generating HTML dashboard report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)). Because 20000 is a huge number.

Go get the best of the non-GUI mode add the JMeter plugin manager. Add the required reports needed by you.

If I am not wrong what you are trying to achieve is a throughput of 20000 per sec. The same can be found using transactions per sec graph from the HTML dashboard report generated in non-GUI mode.

This plugin might help your use case: [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/)

To achieve the desired 20000 users per sec you need to experiment with ramp-up and loop counts based on the output. The end goal should be that your transactions per sec graph should show 20000 or more at one point in time and at the same time the error should be zero then your server is able to handle 20000 users per sec. But average server response time is also an important metric to watch out for. Because no user wants a slow response from the server.

You can also consider the [Concurrency thread group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/). This thread group is specifically designed to generate the desired number of concurrent users.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to do a [Spike Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Spike_testing), like access application with 20 000 users for 1 second - your configuration is fine and and application failed the test so you can raise an issue.

However I'm under impression that your test is kind of short and doesn't tell the full story

1. 20 000 users will produce 20 000 requests per second only if your application response time is 1 second sharp. If your application response time is 0.5 seconds - the load will be 40 000 requests per second, if response time is 2 seconds - the load will be 10 000 requests per second, if response time is 20 seconds - the load will be 1000 requests per second, etc. See [What is the Relationship Between Users and Hits Per Second?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-relationship-between-users-and-hits-second) article for more details if needed.
2. Normally you should increase the load gradually, this way you will have possibility to correlate increasing load with [other metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) (response time, throughput, number of errors, etc) so I would recommend going for ramp-up -> plateau -> ramp-down setting and check the number of requests per second during this "plateau" phase
3. 20000 virtual users is quite a number so make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and it might be the case you will have to go for [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)